# Visual Basic How would I Increment and Decrement a variable with 3 NumericUpDown component (Or Another Method)?

Tags: vb.net, numericupdown

So this is currently what I have on a form:

[image: form]

An example of a users input : 
(E.g `NumericUpDown1` = 3, `NumericUpDown2` = 1, `NumericUpDown3` = 3)

An example of the computer output :
(Points left would = 2, Reasoning : 9- (3+1+3) = 2)

What I want to do with these components is every time "up" is pressed on a `NumericUpDown` I want the points variable to decrease by 1 ( Vise-Versa when down is pressed). The major problem I face is I don't know how to check if a `NumericUpDown` has been pressed up or down.

If you guys know of a different and better way to do this ill 100% be trying that because this way looks horrible.

Comment: Why do you need to increment/decrement a variable? A `NumericUpDown` has a value that you can directly access. Or are you asking us how to update the `Points` control every time that an `NumericUpDown` is changed?

Comment: Update 'Points' every time a NumericUpDown Is changed, so by the end the user should have used up all their points only using NumericUp and NumericDown.

Comment: "Reasoning : (3+1+3) - 9 " does not = 2 it equals -2.

Comment: Whoops, changed it around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like other controls the NumericUpDown has events that can contain your code. The ValueChanged event should work as long as the user uses the up down arrows since the event fires when the user presses these arrows. However, the user can type in an amount in and the event will not fire until the user clicks somewhere else on the form. So you might want to move the code to a button "Update Points" instead of the ValueChanged event.

```
Private Sub NumericUpDowns_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown1.ValueChanged, NumericUpDown2.ValueChanged, NumericUpDown3.ValueChanged
        Dim pointsAvailable = CInt(lblPoints.Text)
        Dim pointsUsed = NumericUpDown1.Value + NumericUpDown2.Value + NumericUpDown3.Value
        lblPoints.Text = (pointsAvailable - pointsUsed).ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm gonna give this a go, can't at the moment until I get on the computer so I'll get back to you. It does look like this will be the answer though.

Answer (score -1):

This should give you everything that you need to figure out how to do what you're asking for:

```
Private Sub NumericUpDowns_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown1.ValueChanged, NumericUpDown2.ValueChanged, NumericUpDown3.ValueChanged
    Me.Label1.Text = (3 * NumericUpDown1.Value + 2 * 3 * NumericUpDown2.Value + 2 * 3 * NumericUpDown3.Value).ToString()
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't get it. Take the OP example "NumericUpDown1 = 3, NumericUpDown2 = 1, NumericUpDown3 = 3" simplifies to 3*3 + 2*3*1 + 2*3*3. Or 9 + 6 + 18 = 33. The OP wanted 2 in the label not 33.

Comment: @Mary - I wasn't trying to give the formula - the OP know that - I was trying to show how to respond to the `NumericUpDown` control changes and to update another control when they change. That's all.